# Convolution layer dimension reduction

Tags: python, image, numpy, neural-network

I am working with the Cifar-10 dataset.  The original shape of the data was (50000, 3072) where there are 50000 images and for each, the first 1024 pixels are red, next 1024 are green, next 1024 are blue. They are stored in row major format, so the first 32 pixels of red are the reds for the first row of 32 pixels.

So far I have managed to transform it into a numpy array of shape (50000, 32, 32, 3)

```
trainX.reshape((-1,3,32,32)).transpose([0,2,3,1])
```

which represents 50000 images, 32 columns by 32 rows and 3 colour intensities per pixel, but I'm having trouble with regularization of the data.

The following averages the intensity across all the colours, but that's not really what should be happening, each colour should average across all of it's own colour's intensities in the data only

```
trainX = (trainX-np.mean(trainX))/np.std(trainX)
```

Is there an efficient way to regularize this data by colour? Is there a more common way to prepare this type of data for input into a convolutional neural network, (such as turning the images to grayscale) or is there a benefit to providing the network with the multiple color planes?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to iterate over the three color intensities?
This could be done in the following way:

```
[(trainX[:,:,:,i]-np.mean(trainX[:,:,:,i]))/np.std(trainX[:,:,:,i]) for i in range(np.shape(trainX)[3])]
```

Comment: I'm trying to edit them in place or return the consolidated object, this creates three separate lists, though slicing the result does get me what I want